# Is there programmatical way to get short day names in windows?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

Is there a way to get a 2 character day-name of the week such as MO/TU/WE/TH/FR/SA/SU?

Currently I only know of using FormatDateTime():

```
 "ddd" returns "Fri"
 "dddd" returns "Friday"
```

The main reason is that I want to obtain localized version of the 1 or 2 character day names:

Say FRIDAY in "ddd" would return:
French Windows = "Vendredi", the 2 char would be "VE", note it's the 1st and 2nd char.
Chinese Windows = "星期五", the char would be "五", note it's the 3rd char.
Japanese Windows = "金曜日", the char would be "金", note it's the 1st char.

**Edit1:**
Currently using Delphi, but i think applies to other languages too.

**Edit2:**
Simply put, I'm looking to obtain the **shorter** version of "ShortDayName" through the use of some functions or constants, so that I don't have to build a table of constants containing the 7 day "Shorter" day names for every possible windows language.

I wonder if such functions really exist.
Maybe the calendar 1 or 2 char day names in Outlook are hard-coded themselves, right?

Comment: What language do you want to use?

Comment: Using Delphi, but applies to other languages too.

Comment: If you're looking for just the first two chars of the word, why not pull back the full string (using "dddd") and then just grab the first two chars and drop the rest?

Comment: Why would Chinese be shortened to just one character? I thought you were asking for two-character names.

Comment: Scott, correct but this would only work alphabets such as western languages, asian languages are different.

Rob, yes I was using alphabets as reference, so it is 2 chars. But for asian languages, it's normally 1 char, don't ask me why, it's a cultural thing :)

Comment: Atlas, I've edited my answer to look more appropriable. See, if that is what you need.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the local names for the days of the week with [ShortDayNames](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=ShortDayNames) and [LongDayNames](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=LongDayNames), and you can use [DayOfWeek](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=DayOfWeek) to get the numeric value for the day.

```
ShortDayNames[Index]; //Returns Fri
```

or

```
LongDayNames[Index]; //Returns Friday
```

The only way I know to shorten them to two chars would be to trim the resulting string

```
LeftStr(LongDayNames[Index],2);//Returns Fr
```

So today's Day would be

```
LeftStr(LongDayNames[DayOfWeek(date)],2); //Returns Fr
```

Answer (score 2):

[Click Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Depicts the standards in custom date formatting.

You may also use the 'ddd' standard and trim it.

Comment: So, which of the things presented on that page gives him anything more than what he already has? Specifically, which part of that page tells how to get two-character day abbreviations? I only see the "ddd" date format, which given a shortened form of unspecified length, which `FormatDateTime` already does.

Comment: Stating the available standards. I did not state on how to alter the standard. I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

Delphi's routines does nothing special - they just ask OS.
Here is how to to it: [Retrieving Time and Date Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319114(VS.85).aspx). I looked through MSDNs docs and found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373890(VS.85).aspx).

Note, that there is no really such thing as "2 character day-name" or "3 character day-name" here. There are: native ("long" in Delphi), abbreviated ("short" in Delphi) or short (Vista and above, not present in Delphi) formats.

For example, abbreviated name of the day of the week for Monday: Mon (3 chars, en-US), Пн (2 chars, ru-RU).

So, you probably look for [LOCALE_SSHORTESTDAYNAMEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373890(VS.85).aspx) format (which is called "short" by MSDN and doesn't appear in Delphi), but it is availavle only on Vista and above.

For example, the following code:

```
const
  LOCALE_SSHORTESTDAYNAME1 = $60;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetThreadLocale($409);
  ShowMessage(
    GetLocaleStr(GetThreadLocale, LOCALE_SSHORTESTDAYNAME1, '') + #13#10 +
    GetLocaleStr(GetThreadLocale, LOCALE_SABBREVDAYNAME1, '')
             );
end;
```

will show you:

> Mo
>
> Mon

But doing this for Russian will output:

> Пн
>
> Пн

Hope my edits make answer more clear ;)

Comment: It's not that the Delphi functions do *nothing*. That's obviously false. They do nothing *special*. They just use the locale strings defined by the OS.

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected my answer. Probably my English isn't good ;)

Comment: Alexander, seems like it is what I was looking for. But I cannot test it since I don't own any Vista, anyone tried this?

Comment: The examples are actual output on my Vista. Sadly, on XP the first line will be empty.